# Get Transition qualifier in chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to find if the url is being accessed is entered by the user or if its something that's being loaded in the background due to other reasons. This information is available through the transaction qualifier that's available in chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted. I want to add this as an additional header information in chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.
However, onCommitted is fired after onBeforeSendHeaders.
Is there any other way to get this information before OnBeforeSendHeaders is fired? I tried chrome.tabs.getCurrent in webNavigation.OnBeforeNavigate, but the callback doesn't have any info in the returned tab object (its undefined).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#relation_to_webRequest and in general give the `webNavigation` docs a thorough read

Comment: Unless I've missed something obvious, the webNavigation docs don't help me much to solve my issue. My assumption is, since a request is initiated by the user by entering the url in the address bar, this information should be available when processing the header. Is this not correct?